# How to get column between two values as per user input

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am stuck on one solution I want to get column as per user in put value.

1. for 1000 Rs. i want all data below 1000.
2. for 2000 Rs. I want data between 1000 & 2000.
3. for 3000 Rs. I want data between 2000 & 3000.
4. for 4000 Rs. I want data between 4000 & 4000.

I have done it like below but it is not working.

```
     $product = Product::select('product_price')
                        ->get();

        foreach ($product as $value) {

            if($value->product_price == 1000){

                  $prod1 = Product::join('company', 'timeline_product.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
                    ->select('company.name', 'company.logo', 'timeline_product.company_id', 'timeline_product.product_name', 'timeline_product.product_desc', 'timeline_product.product_price','timeline_product.reward_points' ,'timeline_product.created_at', 'timeline_product.updated_at')
                    ->where('timeline_product.product_price','<=',1000)
                    ->orderBy('timeline_product.updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->get();

                   // $post = array('result' => $prod1); 

            }elseif ($value->product_price == 2000) {

                    $prod2 = Product::join('company', 'timeline_product.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
                    ->select('company.name', 'company.logo', 'timeline_product.company_id', 'timeline_product.product_name', 'timeline_product.product_desc', 'timeline_product.product_price','timeline_product.reward_points' ,'timeline_product.created_at', 'timeline_product.updated_at')
                    ->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price', [1000, 2000])
                    ->orderBy('timeline_product.updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->get();

                  // $post = array('result' => $prod2); 

            }elseif ($value->product_price == 3000) {

                     $prod3 = Product::join('company', 'timeline_product.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
                    ->select('company.name', 'company.logo', 'timeline_product.company_id', 'timeline_product.product_name', 'timeline_product.product_desc', 'timeline_product.product_price','timeline_product.reward_points' ,'timeline_product.created_at', 'timeline_product.updated_at')
                    ->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price', [2000, 3000])
                    ->orderBy('timeline_product.updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->get();
                  // $post = array('result' => $prod3); 

            }elseif ($value->product_price == 4000) {

                     $prod4 = Product::join('company', 'timeline_product.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
                    ->select('company.name', 'company.logo', 'timeline_product.company_id', 'timeline_product.product_name', 'timeline_product.product_desc', 'timeline_product.product_price','timeline_product.reward_points' ,'timeline_product.created_at', 'timeline_product.updated_at')
                    ->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price', [3000, 4000])
                    ->orderBy('timeline_product.updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->offset($offset)
                    ->get();

                  // $post = array('result' => $prod4); 

            }

        // array_push($product,$post);

        }
```

Please help to achieve the same.
Thanks,

Comment: you want it separated or all in one variable?

Comment: @MohamedSabil83 I want all data in one  if user select 1000 then only output related  to 1000 I want, & same for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this what you need:

```
Product::join('company', 'timeline_product.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
    ->select('company.name', 'company.logo', 'timeline_product.company_id', 'timeline_product.product_name', 'timeline_product.product_desc', 'timeline_product.product_price', 'timeline_product.reward_points', 'timeline_product.created_at', 'timeline_product.updated_at')
    ->when(request('product_price') <= 1000, function ($q) {
        $q->where('timeline_product.product_price', '<=', 1000);
    })
    ->when(request('product_price') > 1000 && request('product_price') <= 2000, function ($q) {
        $q->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price', [1000, 2000]);
    })
    ->when(request('product_price') > 2000 && request('product_price') <= 3000, function ($q) {
        $q->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price', [2000, 3000]);
    })
    ->when(request('product_price') > 3000 && request('product_price') <= 4000, function ($q) {
        $q->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price', [3000, 4000]);
    })
    ->orderBy('timeline_product.updated_at', 'desc')
    ->limit($limit)
    ->offset($offset)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your explanation it seems your product list only have `product_price = 1000, 2000, 3000 and 4000`

So based on current Scenario and your code, it seems you only have four products. Here is a more accurate code which will return you all products in a list based on price -

```
$product = Product::select('product_price')->get();
$prods_according_price = [];
foreach ($product as $value) {
    $end_filter = $value->product_price
    $start_filter = $end_filter - 1000;
    $prods_according_price[$end_filter][] = Product::join('company', 'timeline_product.company_id', '=', 'company.company_id')
        ->select('company.name', 'company.logo', 'timeline_product.company_id', 'timeline_product.product_name', 'timeline_product.product_desc', 'timeline_product.product_price','timeline_product.reward_points' ,'timeline_product.created_at', 'timeline_product.updated_at')
        ->whereBetween('timeline_product.product_price',[$start_filter, $end_filter])
        ->orderBy('timeline_product.updated_at', 'desc')
        ->limit($limit)
        ->offset($offset)
        ->get();
}
print_r ($prods_according_price)
```

You will get output something like -

```
Array(
  [1000] => Array(
      [0] => Array(.....),
      [1] => Array(.....),
     ),
  [2000] => Array(
      [0] => Array(.....),
      [1] => Array(.....),
     ),
  [3000] => Array(
      [0] => Array(.....),
      [1] => Array(.....),
     ),
  [4000] => Array(
      [0] => Array(.....),
      [1] => Array(.....),
     )
)
```

> If there is any typo or Warning in it Let me know. As I didn't executed it.